# How Do You Remodel a Low Poly Game Model for a Cinematic?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am attempting to remodel some the characters from Overwatch to make them look the way they did in the cinematics. The models are very low poly in comparison to the models used for the cinematics. [If you look here and scroll down, you can see the comparisons for the in game model and cinematic model.](http://www.behindthecinematic.com/game/overwatch/trailer/) What I am wondering is how to achieve this. Any help would be very much appreciated. Here is the file for one of the characters if needed:

[image]